# Почему при получении Fragment из BackStack изменения во View не сохраняются

Tags: android, fragment-back-stack

Есть Activity  c FrameLayout и в него по очереди добавляются фрагмент A, затем фрагмент B при помощи

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction transaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentB,tag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Если во фрагменте А, выполнить какие-то действия с интерфейсом (например по клику кнопки загрузить изображение в ImageView )и затем заменить фрагмент А Фрагментом B, то при возвращении по кнопке **Назад** вернется первоначальное View (без загруженного изображения)
Если тоже самое делать с двумя активностями, то проблем нет и View при возвращении по Back выглядит корректно.

В Активности присутствует код:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();

            if(count==0) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }else{
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
        }
    }
```

Что делаю  не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось просто. При создании View  нужно проверять, что она не создана ранее.

```
private View view;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(view==null)    
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);

        return view; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Верно, но более верное решение - построить качественную архитектуру. Как пример MVP. Очень хорошее решение это использование библиотеки [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy).
Дело в том что грамотнее позволить view пересоздаватся когда и как ей хочется, запоминать ее состояние и аттачить его к ней каждый раз после пересоздания.